# how to save state of page html angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I have my parent Component where I add some comoponents childs (when I do my drag and drop)

so I need when I refresh my page the adding of the child component remains displayed on the page 
so how to save the state of my pages in order to when I refresh my page I have always the possibility to add another components

should I use database in server side and how to save it?
thanks in advance

Comment: means you want to go back from child component to parent component

Comment: to simplify is like you take a document word you add some text or tables then you save 

I need to do the some things with angular2 Update my page by adding components or text in DIV then I save this element wich I added

Comment: you can use local storage for it... If you want to use local storage i can provide an example

Comment: yes please if you can thanks

Comment: visit this for general usage of local storage http://stackoverflow.com/a/37680393/5868331

Comment: what is the value should I put in local storage ??

Comment: The element you want to save or any data you want to save from one component to another can be save in this

Comment: I want to save all DIV how get value of this DIV $('#idDIV').html(); some thing like this ?

Comment: @khalil_diouri did you get your solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a **BehaviourSubject(from RxJS)** of type model(this model will be the container for all components) and bind it to your component, so this way whenever anything changes inside your components **BehaviourSubject** is notified and you can subscribe to it and do anything. Thus whenever anything changes inside your page, you can automatically save it to localstorage or server side.
This is an example that does this

https://github.com/rahulkumar66/Outgrow-Builder